# New field not visible in field group on form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have added an extra field to a field group, which already contained 4 fields, this field group is used on the form: smmBusRelTable.

The 4 existings fields are appearing without problems, the new field isn't showing up in the form.

- The field is visible.
- The field exists in the field group on the form.
- I have resetted my personalise screen on that form.
- I can add the field through personalise, but it won't show up.
- It has no CountryCode filled in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you add the field group to a new form or is the field maybe even invisible in the table browser? In the latter case it might be disabled at all via a config key

Comment: The field was showing in a new form, and was visible in het current table browser. Eventually i found out the init method on the form set the visible parameter on false. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

Right clicking on the form and click `restore`.

Go to the control (group, grid, etc) you're expecting to see the fields in, and verify the `DataGroup` property has the correct `Field Group` selected. Try clearing this property, saving, then adding it back again.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help. Eventually i found out the init method on the form set the visible parameter on false. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The init method on the form, set the visible parameter of the field on false. That is why the field showed when i added the field group on a new form.